# Why request.method is not getting invoked?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x, flask

I have a read-only textbox which preloaded value from database which upon a button click sends it's value to a method present in backend to perform `DELETE` query of sql. The problem is occuring when I am click on the button the method is invoked but the `request.method` condition is not invoked. It is directly going to the end `return` statement of the method.

```py
@app.route('/home/delete_reminder/<string:id_val>',methods=['GET','POST'])
@is_logged_in
def delete_reminder(id_val):
    if request.method=='POST':
        desc = request.form['description']
        x = desc.split(',')
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute('DELETE FROM set_reminder WHERE DATE=%s,SUBJECT=%s,DESCRIPTION=%s',[x[0],x[1],x[2]])
        cur.execute('DELETE FROM recur WHERE RECUR_NEXT=%s',[id_val])
        flash('Reminder Deleted','danger')
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cur.close()
    return redirect(url_for('search_reminder_to_delete'))
```

This is my backend code.

```
<form method="POST">
        {% for data in value %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Description</label>
            <input type="text" name="description" class="form-control" readonly="true" value="{{data.DATE}},{{data.SUBJECT}},{{data.DESCRIPTION}}">
        </div>
        <a href="/home/delete_reminder/{{data.RECUR_NEXT}}" class="btn btn-warning" name="delete">Delete Reminder</a>
        {% endfor %}
    </form>
```

This is the html part.

Answer (score -1):

Your button isn't a button, it's a link. You aren't submitting your form.

If you want to fo that then you need to make you form tag:

`<form method="POST" action="/home/delete_reminder/{{data.RECUR_NEXT}}">`

and switch your button to be a real button that submits the form:

```
<div class="button">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Send your message</button>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** Seeing that you want to have multiple possible routes for your form based on the loop.

You could try and use the [`formaction`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_formaction.asp) attribute, although it isn't going to be supported by every browser version.

```
<form method="POST">
{% for data in value %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Description</label>
        <input type="text" name="description" class="form-control" readonly="true" value="{{data.DATE}},{{data.SUBJECT}},{{data.DESCRIPTION}}">
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <button formaction="/home/delete_reminder/{{data.RECUR_NEXT}}" class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Delete Reminder</button>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

However this will still result in your `description` field that is passed to the request having every single description from the whole form in a list or possibly just the last one as a single value (I can't quite remember the behaviour of multiple inputs with the same name), which I don't think is what you're expecting to happen.

It may just be easiest to create a separate form for each link in a loop to be honest:

```
{% for data in value %}
<form method="POST" action="/home/delete_reminder/{{data.RECUR_NEXT}}">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Description</label>
            <input type="text" name="description" class="form-control" readonly="true" value="{{data.DATE}},{{data.SUBJECT}},{{data.DESCRIPTION}}">
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Delete Reminder</button>
        </div>
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: If I put the url in ```action``` then how it will get ```data.RECUR_NEXT``` as ```data``` is part of the loop ?